# Знак при обособлении приложения

Tags: пунктуация

***В 1994 году, в матче-реванше против Тинсли, после шести ничьих и отставки Тинсли из-за плохого самочувствия, Chinook была объявлена чемпионом мира по шашкам в категории «человек-машина». Так, несмотря на то, что Chinook стала чемпионом мира, она не победила лучшего игрока всех времён (*) Тинсли.***

Какой знак — тире или запятую — следует поставить в последнем предложении, перед именем шашиста? Или же тут и не идёт речи об обособлении?

Answer (score 2):

*Так, несмотря на то, что Chinook стала чемпионом мира, она не победила лучшего игрока всех времён - Тинсли.*

В конце предложения приложение обычно обособляется тире, хотя запятая тоже может использоваться. Всё зависит от структуры предложения и от необходимости сделать паузу, чтобы выделить приложение.

В данном случае такая пауза для одиночного приложения в конце распространенного предложения необходима.

Можно сравнить: Это был мой друг, Тинсли. Здесь ставится запятая.